# Find and replace but keep original value in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In the text

```
23:57
Forget Me - Lewis Capaldi
Forget Me
Lewis Capaldi
23:54
Save Me - Wiktoria
Save Me
Wiktoria
23:47
Burn - Ellie Goulding
Burn
Ellie Goulding
```

I would like to enter a ; at the end of all lines because I want to save it as a csv file for further processing. What I have done if search \n and replace it with \n;. After that I have made a whole line of everything and search for ..:.. and replace it with \n to get song and name to start of every line but the problem is that when I search for ..:.. and replace it with a \n I loose the time and I still want the time.

In the end I would like it to be:

```
23:57;Forget Me - Lewis Capaldi;Forget Me;Lewis Capaldi
23:54;Save Me - Wiktoria;Save Me;Wiktoria
23:47;Burn - Ellie Goulding;Burn;Ellie Goulding
```

I have also tried to use [] with $1 but I have too little knowledge and it´s hard to find how to do this. Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d\d:\d\d|\z)`
- Replace with: `;`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    \d\d:\d\d       # 2 digit-colon-2 digit
  |               # OR
    \z              # end of file
)               # end of lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141712/discussion-on-answer-by-toto-find-and-replace-but-keep-original-value-in-notepad).